# Motion detection software

Tags: security, webcam, motion-detection

I have a WMV file that's 5 hours long.  It's mostly just a camera focused on the entry door.

Is there any software where I can throw this file at it and it would find time segments where there is actual movement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transcode the wmv to mjpeg and feed it to [motion](https://motion-project.github.io/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this [CodeProject article on Motion Detection Algorithms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx). Looks really good. Software is freely downloadable and modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Get [Webcam Zone Trigger](http://www.ZoneTrigger.com) - you can use video files as input.

Add a motion detection hot spot on the door. Set its action to take a picture or to make a noise... go to the settings and enable text logs if you want to get a list of all offset time where motion is detected.